# laravel 4 project on shared host displays nothing in browser

Tags: php, apache, laravel

I have a problem deploying Laravel 4 on shared hosting server. Currently I have access to cpanel with PHP version is 5.3.28 ( with no ssh access ).
I created the laravel project on my localhost and it worked pretty well. Then I uploaded all laravel project files to the server and I have changed url variable in app/config/app.php from `http://localhost` to the new address. But when I view my page, browser shows just a blank page.

for testing that, I echoed somthing in index.php and it printed well.
but when I echoed here: `Route::get('/', function(){ echo "hello"; } );` nothing appeared in the page.

here is my .htacess file beside index.php in public folder:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes...
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
```

Comment: Please show us your folder structure. Laravel is a large MVC Framework with hundreds of files and dozens of folders. Having some context would be nice.

Comment: Laravel 4 has a minimum requirement of PHP 5.4, therefore, this isn't gonig to work.

Comment: My folder structure is exactly equal to the default laravel structure.
Also I examine that if I create just a base laravel project in my computer ( works pretty well ) and copy that to my host, again nothing appeared there!

Comment: but according to laravel official site, laravel 4.1 has a minimum requirement of PHP 5.3.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you checked the permission of your app/storage folder?

You need to make it writable by the web server.

For example, on my mac, my web user is _www. So you can use following command to make it work.

```
sudo chown -R _www LARAVEL_PROJECT/app/storage
```

or

```
sudo chown -R a+w LARAVEL_PROJECT/app/storage
```

Comment: actually I haven't access for running sudo command but I try this one: "chmod 777 -R  LARAVEL_PROJECT/app/storage" and now it's working fine for me!